# Android video compression using MediaCodec

Tags: java, android, video, compression

I want to compress an input mp4 video file using android's mediacodec for decoding and encoding and the mp4parser library for muxing to mp4. I found a number of samples on the internet, but none of them are clear to me, and I can't get them to work. 
I know I can use MediaExtractor to read the input file, and decode and encode with 
lower bitrate using MediaCodec, but every code sample crashes horribly. 
The project target is API level 16, so I can't use the MediaMuxer class, and instead want to use mp4parser or some library similar to it. 
Does anyone have experience with this workflow, or knows how to use the MediaCodec class properly to decode an input mp4 and encode it again?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? I am also expecting a sample for video compression.